# Change file picker dialog

Tags: nautilus, xfce, filemanager, thunar

I am using the Xfce desktop and the default file picker dialog seems really out of place. The file picker seems to look a lot like Nautilus even though I don't even have it installed.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: As far as I know, the file picker dialog is part of GTK and there's no way to change it without modifying the source code

Comment: Seems to be the default in 4.12. It's kind of ugly, I have to say. Maybe you can confirm this in the [changelog](http://xfce.org/download/changelogs/4.12). I can't find it myself.

Comment: I think you can change the GTK theme. Also I found instructions to replace GTK dialogs with Qt dialogs: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications#QGtkStyle

Comment: Changing the theme (using `lxappearance`) seems to affect colors, but not icons. Great.